# esri.views.2d.layers.TileLayerView2D, Error: The source image could not be decoded

Tags: arcgis, capacitor, ionic6

I am doing a mobile application with ionic capacitor. After ionic serve test in website, it work normal, but when compile to android app, the basemap layer could not load. It give the error that the source image could not be decoded. I am using the capacitor 5.1.1. If using capacitor 4.0.0, it able work in android. Anyone face this problem before or any idea about this if i want to use capacitor 5.1.1 ? Below is part of my package.json. I am using @arcgis/core 4.26.5. The link image below is the error i get, it cause the basemap layer could not be load, giving a blank basemap layer, but the feature layer all work normally.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@arcgis/core": "^4.26.5",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/badge": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/chooser": "6.4.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "6.4.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-opener": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-path": "6.4.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer": "6.4.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/market": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing": "^6.3.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.1.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/app-launcher": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.2.2",
    "@capacitor/device": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "5.1.1",
    "@capacitor/http": "0.0.3-0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/network": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.4",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.19.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/intro.js": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-chooser": "github:MaximBelov/cordova-plugin-chooser",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "github:Priyansu431/cordova-plugin-file-transfer",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepicker": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-spay": "file:../cordova-plugin-spay",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.4",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "esri-loader": "^2.16.0",
    "intro.js": "^5.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.70",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "togeojson": "^0.16.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/assets": "^2.0.4",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "6.1.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3"
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7MYk.png)

Could anyone help on this ? Or anyone have facing this before or any idea on this ?